# Array sum using Java script

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

****Hi there everyone. I am new to java Script. Just finished functions. I was trying to calculate the sum of an array values. So in this case the desired output would have been 21 but whenever i log on console i keep getting the value 1 . Can someone help****

```
{
let array = [1,2,3,4,5,6] ;
let sum  = 0 ;


function array_sum (){

for (let i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++){

sum = sum + array[i] ;
return sum;
}

}
console.log(array_sum());
```

Comment: Move the return outside of the `for` statement.

Comment: You're returning inside the loop, so there's only ever one iteration before the sum is returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You don't need to return anything from inside the for loop.
2. The final sum would be stored in variable "sum". 
   Try console.log(sum)

Comment: Hi thanks ! i Got the desired output.

Comment: Glad! Could you please upvote and mark as selected if it helped you! Thanks!